# How to use CSS to reproduce the shadow under a device

Tags: css, shadow, box-shadow, css-filters

Is it possible to use CSS to reproduce the shadow under the device of the below image?

The following CSS and different variants don't work:

```
filter: drop-shadow(rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.25) 0px 12px 15px);
```

The problem is concentrating the shadow under the device and flattening it. The CSS above cannot make the shadow appear as if it's projected on the ground.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Crashalot/pen/MWYzoJV

[image: Smartphone with shadow]

Comment: so visually you want a blurred line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pseudo element is better suited to get this done, see below example:

[image: Bottom shadow with pseudo element]

```css
.object {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  background: #E6E6FA;
}
.object:before {
  content:"";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 40%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.55);  
  transform:  scaleX(1.3) scaleY(0.12);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="object"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can use box-shadow:

```css
.object {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  background: #E6E6FA;
  /* This is .shadow-lg from tailwindCSS */
  /* See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow/ */
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="object"></div>
```